# Extracting string with regex retrieves 'True 111499'

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a function, which should retrieve the revision number in a text file. The text file looks like this:

```
componentname1:123456
componentname2:234567
```

The second part is a number, which represents the subversion revision number. The powershell script reads this file line by line and every line is then processed with this function:

```
function getRevision($line) {
    $line -match ":(?<revision>[0-9]*)"
    $result = $Matches['revision']
    Write-Host "Found component revision '$($result)'"
    return $result
}
```

When the function `getRevision` is processed, then it gives the output

```
Found component revision '111499'
```

This function is called by another function like this:

```
$rev = getRevision($Line)
# ....
someOtherFunction -Revision "$($rev)"
```

In this `someOtherFunction`, I now get this output:

```
Handle component with revision 'True 111499'
```

**Edit**
I add the basic code of the function `someOtherFunction`:

```
function someOtherFunction {

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$Revision
    )

    Write-Host "Handle component with revision '$($Revision)'"
}
```

Now, the question occurs: Why is there this `True` stuff? Where is my mistake?

Comment: What does `someOtherFunction` do?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added the code of the function `someOtherFunction`.

Comment: I cannot repro.

Comment: Change first line of `getRevision` to `$line -match ":(?<revision>[0-9]*)" | out-null`, I reproduced it and that helped

Comment: @robdy Thank you, that worked!

Comment: @kristian - glad to hear! I'll rewrite this to an answer so you could accept it if you don't mind

Comment: Probably you might just use `$line -replace ".*:"` to remove all text up to and including the last `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `True` is from `-match` operator in first line of your function

```
$line -match ":(?<revision>[0-9]*)"
```

If `-match` is executed inside the function, its output (binary value) is added automatically to the output of your function and then `$result` is being added as a second element. Therefore if you check the value of `$rev` you'll see:

```
PowerShell> $rev
True
123456
```

If you want to get rid of the first element you just need to pipe it to `Out-Null`:

```
$line -match ":(?<revision>[0-9]*)" | Out-Null
```

**Edit**: as pointed out by Matt, if `$line` doesn't match with the pattern, it may return unexpected results (last successful match). To prevent this you could use:

```
if ($line -match ":(?<revision>[0-9]*)") {
    $result = $Matches['revision'] 
    Write-Host "Found component revision '$($result)'"
    return $result}
else {return $false}
```

In this case `Out-Null` is not needed as `-match` inside `if` condition is not being added to the output.

Comment: Given the logic I would instead add that clause into an if or even better a where clause. If the source data had something that didnt match you would get odd output otherwise. Just some basic data validation. Not _required_ of course

Comment: Thanks @Matt - added this.

Answer (score 2):

If that is how your source data is formed i.e colon delimited key value pairs. I think [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-6) removes all of the "complexity" from this issue. It however wants "key=value" so we need to make a small change and, in the end, you get the whole file as a hashtable.

If that sample data was in a file called c:\temp\file.txt

```
$revisions = (Get-Content -Raw C:\temp\file.txt) -replace ":","=" | ConvertFrom-StringData
$revisions['componentname1']
```

If there was a risk of bad data you could do some *basic* filtering by only working with lines that have colons:

```
$data = (Get-Content  C:\temp\file.txt | Where-Object{$_ -match ":"}) -replace ":","=" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData
$data['componentname1']
```